# .net process incoming email

Tags: .net, smtp

I need to receive email and parse and act on the contents programatically.

I've done this before by setting up a postfix server and piping the incoming mail to a php script that handles this.

That would be overkill though for a new project i'm working on.

I'm hoping someone knows of a library or existing utility that would listen for incomming email and then allow me to pipe it or run some .net code on the contents of the message.

This doesn't need to be a fully functional smtp client/server.  It just needs to be able to handle a specific email from a specific address with a specific format.  I can take care of all that, I just need to get access to the email contents.  Server environment is win 2008, .net 4

Answer (score 3):

Fully functional c# coded mail server with source:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/SMTP_POP3_IMAP_server.aspx

Latest in:
http://www.lumisoft.ee/lsWWW/download/downloads/

You can write message filter for it or implement own server using SMTP server component.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://ndumbster.sourceforge.net/default.html. This is the complete source code for a fake smtp server. Hack your code right in.

Answer (score 1):

If you are processing *incoming* email, and smtp server is not what you want to use (that is for *outgoing* messages).

Either POP or IMAP is probably what you need (depending on the connection you have to the mail server that is receiving the message).

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Pop3MailClient.aspx) might help.

Comment: POP and IMAP are protocols used for downloading or syncing already delivered email. SMTP is the protocol used to send and receive email. When your mail client sends an email it talks to a SMTP server using the SMTP protocol. That SMTP server then sends the email to another SMTP server as indicated by the domains mx record.  This second SMTP server receives the email from the first SMTP server, and then does something with it (Like saving the message in a specific users email box, which can later be retrieved with POP or IMAP). So yes, I need a script-able SMTP server that can receive email.

Comment: sorry if that sounded snarky, limited character count for comments, hard to convey tone.  I do appreciate your response though, and the link you provided will be useful none the less.